# Misusing small font size as subscript

Tags: fonts, faces

For typing mathematical formulas in emacs I often run into the problem that certain characters are not available as subscript (or superscript) characters. Since I would like a simple solution without involving rendering of LaTeX formulas I was wondering if I could put characters with a small font size to simulate subscript.

Here my questions:

1. Can I directly change the font of a displayed character in a buffer (maybe using overlays etc)?
2. Can I display character of a buffer using different charsets that involve e.g. the same font but with different font sizes (one for normal character and the other for "subscript").
3. Is there a different/easier solution?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Question 1 & 2: yes this is possible, through Text Properties.  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TextProperties and `faces`

Comment: Great! Thank you very much @jue :)!